# Can you claim a portion of proceeds from an iOS in-app purchase go to charity?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Apple has strict guidelines dictating no charitable donations and the app has to be free if there are...

> 21. Charities and contributions
>
>     - 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free.
>     - 21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS.

I want to monetize the app and donate a portion to charity so free isn't an option.

What if I had something in the app where it said 40% of proceeds went to charity, that way apple would get 30% from the in-app purchase, I would keep roughly 30% and the charity would get 40%.

I am hoping that this would work because I am the one donating a portion of the proceeds and it is not an outright donation.

Also, would I be allowed to advertise "40% of proceeds go to charity" in the app?

Can not find any documentation on this, would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Well you could donate some of the money you make selling the app to charity...

Comment: @Keyboard_Gamer he is asking whether or not Apple will allow his app to make this “proceeds go to charity” claim.